# Default folder/file created ACL permissions not correct

Tags: permissions, acl

I have applied the following settings to my core html folder:

```
chown :ftpaccess html -R
chmod 0775  html -R
setfacl -R -d -m group:ftpaccess:rwx html
```

However whenever anyone creates a new file or folder in the html (or subfolder) it doesn't default to user:ftpaccess with 0775 permissions.

What I get (created as root in nano is):

```
getfacl test2.txt
# file: test2.txt
# owner: root
# group: root
user::rw-
group::rwx                      #effective:rw-
group:ftpaccess:rwx             #effective:rw-
mask::rw-
other::r--
```

What do I need to do to make this apply to subdirectories? I thought the -d would have fixed that. Is it something to do with sticky ?

Answer (score 0):

you have to set the default for the user also:

```
setfacl -R -d -m user:ftpaccess:rwx html
```

the above command will set the default for the existing folder recursively, if you want apply this ACL for files and folder remove the `-d` options.

Comment: Not sure how this helps as this comes from my actual question?

Answer (score 0):

So it appears I am not alone in my problems - and I have since found this great article from 2010:

http://brunogirin.blogspot.com/2010/03/shared-folders-in-ubuntu-with-setgid.html

It would appear that I haven't also re-mounted the partition which would account for why it didn't work as well as running `chmod g+s html`.